# Connecting Qt5 and Firebird 2.5

Tags: c++, odbc, firebird, qt5

I'm a newbie at c++ linking and databases, so may be i'm asking a really stupid question. Anyway, i'm trying to access to firebird database using Qt5 for Windows. I've checked google and found 2 ways of doing so:

1. build ibase driver from Qt source;
2. use firebird through ODBC driver.

**Software versions**

I'm using latest version of Qt: 5.1.1. Firebird 2.5 is working ok: i've create a `test_base` and test user `admin`. Administartion of `test_base` i've done through FlameRobin.

**Building**

I've downloaded qt5.1.1 source and unpacked it in c:/devtools/qt5.1.1-src. Since Qt4.7-4.8 folder and project structure has been changed so old FAQs cannot be applied here. So i tried to build sql.pro from qtbase\src\sql folder with 2 lines added:

> INCLUDEPATH+=  C:/devtools/firebird/firebird_2_5/include
>
> LIBS+=         C:/devtools/firebird/firebird_2_5/lib/fbclient_ms.lib

And i've added C:/devtools/firebird/firebird_2_5/lib/ and C:/devtools/firebird/firebird_2_5/include in system PATH. Compilation is done without any error and i get a `qt_pch.h.gch\c++` file in build dir. And i have no idea what's to do next, because i hoped to have bunch of .a and .dll files or bunch of error at least.

**Using ODBC driver**

I've downloaded and installed firebird ODBC driver from [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/). Installation was successful and i created ODBC DSN source `mydb` in Windows ODBC manager. Test connection button from ODBC configurator says that everything is ok.

Next thing i did was opening SQL Browser example from Qt Creator. And it fails to open my ODBC base with following parameters:

- Driver: QODBC
- Database Name: mydb
- Username: admin
- Password: admin
- Hostname: localhost
- Port: Default

And i get an error message: "[ODBC Firebird Driver] Unable to connect to data source: library 'C:\devtools\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll' failed to load QODBC3: Unable to connect".

I'm looking for resolving any of this two issues. Thanks in advance.

upd: i've connected firebird database through ODBC: the error was in using x64 database with x86 QODBC. Nota bene: in order to manage x86 DSN ODBC in x64 Windows 7 one must run ODBC manager from `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` NOT from Administration Panel as it explained [here](http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/windows-x64-32bit-odbc-vs-64bit-odbc/).

But what about building ibase from qt source?

Comment: You provide a lot of background, but it is unclear to me what your (remaining) problem is. You might want to update your question to ask a more specific and explicit question.

Comment: More specific question is: how to build ibase driver from Qt5.1.1 source? Why does building ends with mystery `.c++` file without any error?

Comment: src/sql is the location of the libqtsql library, but what you're trying to achieve is to build the ibase plugin, which would be src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase/ibase.pro. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtsql/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qibase-plugin-on-windows